# What are the pros and cons of selling rooted androids for resale "as-is" to the general public?

Tags: root-access

For my question, let me give some background.  My business is to data clear phones and tablets. I've been tasked with research into rooted devices. I have a very basic grasp of this concept. I think what I've found is that rooted devices can be 'unrooted' but only if one knows what rooted it originally. I've found this:

You’ll have to use either a terminal emulator or ADB. Here are the commands to uninstall it:

mount -o remount,rw /system
rm /system/app/Superuser.apk

Would that be a good way to remove the root from all cells across the board?

Specifically what I need to know is what do rooted devices mean to the cell phone data clear industry? Is there user data in a rooted device after data clearing it manually?

Comment: Please edit your question and write a more meaningful title. See also http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/a/1182/440 I guess one approach would be to flash the stock ROM **followed** by a factory reset.

Answer (score 2):

Since a device is "rooted" (*generic Android device, no names of manufacturers, this is just a guideline, mileage will vary*), chances are:

- boot-loader is unlocked
- custom recovery is installed

The above two usually go hand-in-hand together, along with running a perhaps, custom ROM.

If the above criteria is held true for that said device, then its a matter of issuing a fast-boot to format all partitions individually as in using `fastboot erase xxxxx` where xxxxx is one of:

- boot
- recovery
- data
- system

That, may fit the criteria to the vague representation of **data clearing industry**, or some standard that was stipulated and to be carried out as per the OP's question.

Comment: Samsung phones don't have fastboot remember, or a bootloader for that matter.

Comment: Who says Samsung.... OP never mentioned a thing about it!!!

Comment: They were being general, so make sure you cover all the corners ;)

Comment: I realize my question was not the best. I am really trying to understand this topic by deadline time and realizing I  need way more time. My supervisor is leaning towards the belief that these cells are data cleared. But with root access on them, I disagree and I need to be certain. Thank you all for your input.